# Background image for navigation disappears once published

Tags: navigation, image-display

I'm creating one page at my work intranet Sharepoint site. I'm trying to customize the navigation only for my one page. My navigation bar looked good in preview mode, with the background images appearing and hoover working, but when I publish, my background images for my navigation disappears. When I go back to html code after publishing, I find the inline code for my images has disappeared. This happens every time I try to publish. I'm new at this so would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: post some html code, how are you referencing the image files..

Comment: Hi Arsalan,

http://icant.co.uk/articles/flexible-css-menu/step1.html

Comment: No.. you referred to background images right? Show the code you have written for the page..?

Comment: So from the homepage, I go to add page, then edit html, edit source, and i paste my html with the css above it. When I click ok, the images and everything appear correctly.  The images have already been uploaded and I just link to the folder they are in. Like this: 
#nav{
  clear:both;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#666;
  margin-left:4px;
  float:left;
  list-style-type:none; 
  background:url(PublishingImages/navshadow.gif) no-repeat 8px 100% #fff;
  padding-bottom:21px;

Comment: yes, background image, but for the navigation bar, so it can look different when my mouse hoovers over it. like the link i sent. I basically followed this for the code http://icant.co.uk/articles/flexible-css-menu/step2.html

Comment: I'm assuming it's something to do w/ the parent master css that I need to do an override for just for my one page? but i'm not sure how..

Comment: [How to get url of the image in CSS](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44997/how-to-get-url-of-the-image-in-css), your problem is with relative URL of the image! either put the images in Style Library and css in style library too, and then try giving relative path according to css file path... or put the images in 14 hive folder and give path like '/_layouts/images/imagename.png'

Comment: Ah ok. It does help to know what my issue is. I guess I've been researching the wrong question then. Thanks! I'll try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

[How to get url of the image in CSS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44997/how-to-get-url-of-the-image-in-css), your problem is with relative URL of the image! either put the images in Style Library and css in style library too, and then try giving relative path according to css file path... or put the images in 14 hive folder and give path like '/_layouts/images/imagename.png'

If this works for you, mark as answer!

Comment: Okay, so I've put the CSS and the images in the Style Library. Now the images are referenced like this 

background:url("/Style%20Library/Images/BenTabActive.gif") transparent top right no-repeat ;

but the navigation images are still not showing up. It's listed out as a bulleted list, or it shows up in preview and disappears again when I publish

I came across this http://www.isurinder.com/blog/post/2011/02/03/Reference-Custom-CSS-and-JavaScript-files-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx#.UMj0iflYTng and tried referencing that way, but it's still not working...

Comment: Seems like you have `htttp` which should be `http`, also if images and css both are in Style Library root - just use the image names... no need for any path!

Comment: Thanks for your help Arsalan but I still can't figure this out. I tried putting the CSS and the images in Style Library, and putting the following reference at the top of my html:
<link href="http://portal/Style%20Library/sitename/Nav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
When I do that, again the navigation shows up correctly in preview, but once I publish, it reverts to list mode and the images disappear. When I go back into html mode, the link reference to the css has disappeared.